# HMAC MD5 with meteor

Tags: meteor, md5, hmac

I need to generate an HMAC MD5 hash in my meteor app. I've already looked at crypto-base and crypto-md5 and both don't have HMAC implemented. I've tried copying hmac.js from https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ but I get an error about "this" being undefined.

Does an HMAC implementation exist or do I have to create/port one for meteor ?

Comment: Are you doing this in client or server code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the server, I believe you can use Node's [Crypto module](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhmac_algorithm_key):

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var crypto = Npm.require('crypto');
  crypto.createHmac('md5', secretKey).update(message).digest('base64');
}
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: let me try it out today. I'll comment once I have. Thank you.

Comment: We do this, pretty much.  Works well.